# drawContour doesn't do what I want

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I am trying really hard to find contours in this image:

[image]

here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
im = cv2.imread('test.jpg')

##imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.namedWindow('gray',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow('gray',im)
cv2.waitKey()
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray, 0, 255, 
 cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_LIST, 
cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

print ("number of countours detected before filtering %d -> "%len(contours))

new = np.zeros(im.shape)
new = cv2.drawContours(im,contours,-1,(0,0,255))

cv2.namedWindow('Display',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow('Display',new)
cv2.waitKey()
```

[image: output]

Problems: 1. the produced image is always completely black and it never shows anything, just pure black image. by my description you can realize i am new to image processing. i am trying to show the body contour in red color but nothing appears.

I am using open cv 3.4.0 and python 3.6

any suggestions / solutions are welcome, thank you.

Comment: not answer, but I would suggest use something like `floodfill` first to cut clear body out

Comment: With the commented out `cvtColor`, that won't run at all. Otherwise it works as I'd expect, finding some ~1500 contours, one of which is a contour of that person. The rest are either noise, or internal contours, since you just used `cv2.RETR_LIST` and don't do any filtering on the output.

Comment: @DanMašek, Hi, the test.jpg image is greyscale 1 channel image. previously it was a color image but since i changed it to greyscale from outside manipulation, I commented out that line. you are correct, i had like 1700 contours, I only want the biggest contour, the whole body contour. thanks for your hlp and lookign for suggestions.

Comment: @MonirulIslam use `cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL` instead.

Comment: @JeruLuke, this worked! thank you so much!. how do i accept this as an answer?

Comment: It doesn't matter that it's grayscale on the disk. The second parameter of `imread` has default value of `IMREAD_COLOR`, which means the image is always loaded as BGR.

Comment: @MonirulIslam check out the answer now !! Is there anything else to add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `cv2.RETR_LIST`, you must use `cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL`.

- `cv2.RETR_LIST` is used when you want to list all the contours in your image.
- Sometimes there might be contours within some contours. The ones on the outside are called **parent**, while the ones on the inside are called **child**. When you only want these **parent** contours use `cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL`.

You can find more about this on [THIS LINK](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_hierarchy/py_contours_hierarchy.html#contours-hierarchy)

Comment: this fixed the problem